# How to get the current activity and compare it and do some action?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, onbackpressed

I have 2 activities and 4 fragments. I just want the code to close only when the user is on the MainActivity or welcome_fragment (I have named it that way)

I wrote some pseudocode below to help you understand my question:

Note: This code should be written under onBackPressed method in MainActivity

```
if(currentactivity/currentfragment)==MainActivity/welcome_fragment)
{
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

How do I get the current fragment or activity's id to compare it with "R.id.welcome_fragment" (or something else) and then and only then close the app onbackpressed?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the "on the MainActivity" requirement as overriding `onBackPressed` in the `MainActivity` ensures that it only runs there. As far as the `welcome_fragment` is concerned you can do this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ... {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        final Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.primary_content);
        if (WelcomeFragment.class.isInstance(currentFragment)) {
            // The current fragment is a WelcomeFragment. Do something here...
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Replacing `R.id.primary_content` with the id of your fragment container and `WelcomeFragment` with the actual class that is your welcome_fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The only place you should call `super.onBackPressed()` is in an override of `onBackPressed()`.  If that override is in `MainActivity`, and you haven't extended `MainActivity`, there's no need to test what activity is running.

It sounds like what you really want to do is override `onBackPressed()` in the *other* activity and have it *not* call super.  Be warned that changing the behavior of the navigation bar buttons is generally bad UX and may lead to uninstalls.